# Getting a Reference to ViewHolder on RecyclerView Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my first attempt at implementing the `RecyclerView`. I have implemented a `Callback` interface between the `Adapter` and the `ViewHolder` Class to handle Click Events on the UI elements (buttons). I am having problems getting a reference to the `ViewHolder` that the click occurred in. I can click the `Button` for the first item in the list, however the action that i'd defined is performed on the last `viewholder` in my recycler view. I finally figured out to pass the position through my interface, but I'm struggling to understand how to get a reference to that viewholder` from it.

```
    public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.RoomViewHolder>
{
    List<Room> mRooms;
    public RoomAdapter(List<Room> rooms) {
        mRooms = rooms;
    }

    @Override
    public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        final View viewItem = LayoutInflater
                .from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.room_rv_item,viewGroup,false);
        return vh = new RoomViewHolder(viewItem,new IRoomViewClick() {
            @Override
            public void editname(int pos) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder roomViewHolder, int i) {
        Room r = getItem(i);
        roomViewHolder.label.setText(r.name);


    }
    public Room getItem(int position)
    {
        return mRooms.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mRooms.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRooms.size();
    }

    public static class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        TextView label;
        Button editBtn;
        LinearLayout labelView;
        Button saveBtn;
        Button deleteBtn;
        EditText editNameET;
        IRoomViewClick mListener;
        public RoomViewHolder(View itemView, IRoomViewClick listener) {
            super(itemView);
            labelView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.labelview);
            mListener = listener;
            editBtn =(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editbtn);
            editBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_listitem_label);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos = getPosition();
            mListener.editname(pos);



        }
    }
    public static interface IRoomViewClick
    {
        public void editname(int pos);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Would that not just get me a ref to the button instead of the ViewHolder itself?

Comment: heh ... i didn't read the question carefully ... i thought that you need a position (since i did not see getPosition()'s body in your code) ... but yes, you can put there ViewHolder instead ... but then you will not know the position, since ... well, it is RecyclerView and view/viewholder can be ...  recycled ...

Comment: Yeah I missed implementing the getPosition() function in my code. That probably did not help. I'm still not completely clear on setting and getting tags, and converting that into a ViewHolder that I can manipulate.

Comment: Tag is an object..  You can put there any object but after getting it you have to cast it to proper class

Comment: I understand that, at what point in the lifecycle do I set and get the tags, and what object do i tag and what do I tag it with?

Comment: I think I figured it out. The Solution was to tag the roomholder itemview with the roomholder object in the onBindViewHolder event.

Comment: Why are you keeping a reference to the last ViewHolder you've created? (`RoomViewHolder vh;`)

Comment: it's just cruft from trying different things.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can set a tag for the `editBtn` in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
    public RoomViewHolder(View itemView, IRoomViewClick listener) {
        ....
        editBtn =(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editbtn);
        //add tag for this view
        editBtn.setTag(this);
        ....
   }
```

and get it in `onClick`

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //getTag
        RoomViewHolder holder = (RoomViewHolder )(view.getTag());
        int pos = getPosition();
        mListener.editname(pos);
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Unbelievable that Google did not think of better way of doing it - almost year passed and there is no better way to get ViewHolder that via old setTag method (that was part of view holder unofficial pattern)...

Answer (score 13):

Actually you can do better than `getTag` by calling `getChildViewHolder(View child)` on the RecyclerView:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyHolder holder = (MyHolder) mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
    holder.textView.setText("Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: it will give all views in the item can be  accessed or only clicked item? https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper/issues/594

Comment: When the view is clicked, this function will access that view which is clicked.  But other than it being in the `onClick` handler, it can get views which are clicked or not.

Comment: thanks, I'm thinking getting bitmap form recyclerview displayed imageviews drawable to share via whatsapp !! getting the image fromcache working fine but it's very slow (Using fresco )!!

Comment: Yeah if you're getting from cache you're accessing the db. If you have some small images, better to keep them around.

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int pos = getAdapterPosition(); //getPosition() is deprecated 
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
```

notifyItemChanged will notify your onBindViewHolder, then you can do something like this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder roomViewHolder, int i) {
    Room r = getItem(i);
    roomViewHolder.label.setText(r.name);
    if(i == pos){ // Do Something }

}
```

Whenever you click the item, it will change pos' value and trigger the // Do Something

Answer (score 2):

Turn out that `RecycleView` saves the view position in the view layout params, so if you just want the view position from to get the right item from the list you can use this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
lp.getViewPosition();
```

Comment: `getViewPosition` is deprecated, you should now use `getViewLayoutPosition` or `getViewAdapterPosition`, usually the latter.