# Large gap between RecyclerView items

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

after I run my application I get large gap between RecyclerView items !!
this is my code here : [Github](https://github.com/userRidae/RecyclerView)
[Large gap between recyclerview items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jxSt.png)

[image]

Comment: Share your xml file

Comment: you can see it here https://github.com/userRidae/RecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your Layouts like this

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.breuhteam.recyclerview.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**view_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/itemView"
    android:src="@drawable/diy"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks it work for me but when I scoll down and I want to go back to up item some item size change

Comment: it's because of recyclerview every time create the new view, you have to setTag for your items.

Comment: how can I do that plese !!?

Comment: example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889361/getting-a-reference-to-viewholder-on-recyclerview-click

Comment: This answer worked for me thanks @UttamPanchasara .

Comment: The layout_margin and adjustViewBounds properties are important and not mentioned by most answers.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem but with text but I think it doesnt matter

We need to change the height of the constraint layout to wrap content instead match parent [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWNwA.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).