# RecylerView not rendring images after changing layout width and height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this **RecyclerView**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

if I changes height from **match_parent** to **wrap_content** it won't display images but otherwise does, what's wrong with it.

**MainActivity layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rcView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Recylerview Item Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You should show adapter and layout of item

Comment: Ok let me add that.

Comment: RecyclerView is scrollable view so you should not to put wrap_content the height of RecyclerView. It will show only one item in screen

Comment: @HiteshSarsava but what difference does that make if it's scrollable?

Comment: ues LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead of RelativeLayout in `MainActivity layout` and set wrap_content to height of reclerview.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan nope, it isn't work.

Comment: How do you load image @Pra

Comment: @MeosCoder using Picasso.

Comment: set orientation  to vertical in linearlayout of recylerview item layout

Comment: @MohammedFarhan did that.

Comment: did it work or not?

Comment: Nope it didn't.

Comment: @Prashant Because the data in the Scrollable View will be more than the mobile screen. thats why we are putting scrollable Views. so in scrollable views set height always match_parent

Comment: post you adapter code.

Comment: You imageview shows and your image does not, is it?, Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Khemraj Not really if i chanage height of RecyclerView to wrap_content no images shown, if I set it to match_parent all images shown.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan not able to add Adapter code as it says too much code.

Comment: First of all set image view height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution it is **AdjustViewBounds** property for ImageView. After setting it to true now I can adjust the height and width the **recycler_view_item**  the way I want.

Here is revised code for **recycler_view_item**.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476611/large-gap-between-recyclerview-items?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) was also helpful.