# expandable recyclerview update from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I'm using a expandable recyclerview in my project, the data is provided from a firebase consulting.

The expandable recyclerView that I use is: [bignerdranch](http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)

What is the best way for update my view, because the site says:

> Please note that the traditional `notifyDataSetChanged()` of RecyclerView.Adapter does not work as intended

and recommend use:

> // Child Changes
>
> `notifyChildInserted(int parentPosition, int childPosition)`
>
> ...

However, I don't know the childPositions that as changed.

Comment: Using a "click listener" you get the view, and the viewholder and the adapter position using library methods. If it is not a very long list, you can iterate from the first position to the clicked position (parent ? count=0 : count++), count is your childposition after the loop. If you check their code, youll find a place where they do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very proud of this solution, due to the loop, but this is an alternative for short lists:

You can get the clicked view from a listener, the viewHolder from the view and the adapter position from the view holder, finally use these methods:

[Use this method](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/ChildViewHolder.java#L62)

```
/**
 * Returns the adapter position of the Child associated with this ChildViewHolder
 *
 * @return The adapter position of the Child if it still exists in the adapter.
 * RecyclerView.NO_POSITION if item has been removed from the adapter,
 * RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() has been called after the last
 * layout pass or the ViewHolder has already been recycled.
 */
@UiThread
public int getChildAdapterPosition() {
    int flatPosition = getAdapterPosition();
    if (mExpandableAdapter == null || flatPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }

    return mExpandableAdapter.getChildPosition(flatPosition);
}
```

[Also see](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java#L780)

```
/**
 * Given the index relative to the entire RecyclerView for a child item,
 * returns the child position within the child list of the parent.
 */
@UiThread
int getChildPosition(int flatPosition) {
    if (flatPosition == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int childCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < flatPosition; i++) {
        ExpandableWrapper<P, C> listItem = mFlatItemList.get(i);
        if (listItem.isParent()) {
            childCount = 0;
        } else {
            childCount++;
        }
    }
    return childCount;
}
```

An easy way to define the listener [here](https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/).

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        // do it
    }
});
```

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716024/1009132) to get the viewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MyHolder holder = (MyHolder) mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
    holder.textView.setText("Clicked!");
}
```

Check the [view type](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view/blob/28858de8c9884f4b5607edcebab2c66cb0a30ddd/expandablerecyclerview/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/expandablerecyclerview/ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.java#L262) to [know when](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) the clicked view is a parent or a child

```
  //Returns the view type of the item at position for the purposes of view recycling.
  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (items.get(position) instanceof User) {
          return USER;
      } else if (items.get(position) instanceof String) {
          return IMAGE;
      }
      return -1;
  }
```